# Help a DND noob out? Proficiency and how it is used?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, proficiency

I am extremely new to D&D and I'm filling out a 5th edition character sheet for the first time. I chose my race as elf and it says, "You have proficiency in the Perception skill." What's proficiency? How do I fill it out, what do I write? And also how would it be used in combat..?

Just explain it to me as if I am five years old. A scenario would be nice.. Sorry for the trouble, first time with RPG games as well

Comment: VTC, The suggested question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Joshua Alan Smith "I am reading the final playtest rules" FWIW, the question TuggyNe linked to was not the finished form of the rules, so I suggest it is not really a duplicate ...  but as nothing changed I can see how "dupe" might be a good call.  Added new player and proficiency as tags in the edit.